# Yii2 - wrong order of loaded CSS - extension's CSS breaks the layout

Tags: php, html, css, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Yii2 (v2.014), hail812/yii2-adminlte3, kartik-v/DatePicker.

Any page with a rendered datepicker breaks the theme. The font is smaller as expected, some other issues are noticable. I have found out, that the datepicker add additional css files in the html header. But instead of placing these lines AFTER the theme, they popup before all other "<link rel=stylesheet" lines. This is probably the reason for the broken layout. Is there any way to controll which order are the CSS files from plugins/extensions loaded?

Comment: Yii loads additional css files via `yii\web\AssetBundle`s in the order they are added. Assets can have requirements. If an Asset has an requirement of another Asset then the requirement Asset is being loaded before. You can figure out what additional assets are being loaded if you find the extension in your vendor folder and search for the Asset file.

Comment: As a fix for this (which i do not recommend) is to remove the CSS file from the extensions assets. Then you can manually decide where to load the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I have found was not exactly managing the order of CSS files, but a option in pamars.php. After setting the 'bsDependencyEnabled' => false, the page was displayed without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The **Yii** way of doing this would be using the `AssetManager`

`AssetManager` lets you configure the bundles both, in the `php` class, and in the application configuration. If you are using the basic template, that would be `config/web`.

You would configure the extension asset bundles to depend on the ones that you want to include before them, for example:

```php
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'kartik\date\DatePickerAsset' => [
                'depends' => [
                    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
                    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset'
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

On the code block above `kartik\date\DatePickerAsset` is just an example, you need to find the names of the other assets you want to configure and add them.